# Embedded font not working in mxml, despite following embed-as-CFF advice

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I'm trying to embed a font face in mxml/flex

I've read the articles that talk about embed-as-cff: true being for spark components and embed-as-cff: false being for mx.

I've tried using all 4 possible combinations of mx:label, s:label, embed-as-cff: true and embed-as-cff: false, but nothing doing

```
<fx:Style>
    @font-face { 
    src: url("assets/fonts/EXO2-LIGHT.TTF"); 
    fontFamily: exo2; 
    embed-as-cff: true;
     }
 @font-face { 
    src: url("assets/fonts/EXO2-LIGHT.TTF"); 
    fontFamily: exo3; 
    embed-as-cff: false;
  }
  </fx:Style>
  ...

    <s:Label styleName="applicationTitle" 
      fontFamily="exo2"  top="0" text="Service Capacity Forecast" 
      buttonMode="true"      useHandCursor="true"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally nailed it after a lot of trial and error.
The styleName attribute referred to a style containing

```
fontWeight:bold;
```

and the font type I am using does not include a bold type.
Instead of defaulting to the non-bold (regular) font, Flex decided that respecting the bold attribute was more important than the fontFamily.

Answer (score 2):

can you try for `.otf` instead of `.ttf` Here is some code which is working for both spark & mx

```
@font-face {
   src: url('assets/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Roman.otf');
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
   embedAsCFF: false;
}

@font-face {
   src: url('assets/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Bold.otf');
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue Bold";
   embedAsCFF: false;
}
```